# Trouble printing errors with django forms

Tags: python, django

working on django forms here and i've trouble with errors. I know how to detect them but i cannot (for some reasons) print an error under a form when is is uncorrect.

The class :

```
class descclient_form(forms.Form):

TYPE_CHOICE = (
('C', ('Client')),
('F', ('Facture')),
('V', ('Visite'))
)

file_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices = TYPE_CHOICE, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
file_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
file_cols = forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.Textarea)
# file_date = forms.DateField()
file_sep = forms.CharField(max_length=5, initial=';')
file_header = forms.CharField(max_length=200, initial='0')

# Check if file_cols is correctly filled
def clean_cols(self):
    cleaned_file_type = self.cleaned_data.get("file_type")
    cleaned_file_cols = self.cleaned_data.get("file_cols")

    if cleaned_file_type == 'C':
        if 'client' not in cleaned_file_cols:
            self._errors['file_cols'] = [u'Requiers \'Client\' in collumn selection']
            print 'error'
    if cleaned_file_type == 'F':
        mandatory_field = ('fact', 'caht', 'fact_dat')
        for mf in mandatory_field:
            if mf not in cleaned_file_cols:
                self._errors["file_cols"] = self.error_class(['Requiers \'fact\', \'caht\' \'fact_dat\ in file_cols'])
                print 'error'
    return self.cleaned_data
```

Here is the function called :

```
def descclient(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = descclient_form(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.clean_cols()
return render_to_response('descclient.html', {'form': descclient_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And Template :

```
<form action="/descclient" method="post">
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.file_type_errors }}
    <label for="id_subject">File type:</label>
    {{ form.file_type }}
</div>

<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.file_name_errors }}
    <label for="id_subject">File name:</label>
    {{ form.file_name }}
</div>

<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.file_cols_errors }}
    <label for="id_subject">Collumns:</label>
    {{ form.file_cols }}
</div>

<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.file_sep_errors }}
    <label for="id_subject">Separator:</label>
    {{ form.file_sep }}
</div>

<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.file_header_errors }}
    <label for="id_subject">Header:</label>
    {{ form.file_header }}
</div>
{% csrf_token %}
<p><input type="submit" value="Validate"></p>
```

For some reaons the "{{ form.file_cols_errors }}" doesn't print anything

EDIT :

So, as pointed i changed the clean_cols method to clean. I must be some kind of lost because it doesn't even get into the if statement

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(descclient_form, self).clean()
    cleaned_file_type = cleaned_data("file_type")
            cleaned_file_cols = cleaned_data("file_cols")

    if cleaned_file_type == 'C':
        if 'client' not in cleaned_file_cols:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This field throws an error")
    if cleaned_file_type == 'F':
        mandatory_field = ('fact', 'caht', 'fact_dat')
        for mf in mandatory_field:
            if mf not in cleaned_file_cols:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This field throws an error")
    return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should raise a ValidationError in a "clean_file_cols" method:

```
raise forms.ValidationError("This field throws an error")
```

For details, have a look [at the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute). And btw: You should avoid using "print" anywhere in your django project, because on most webserver configuration, it leads to a server error. Use logging instead.

Comment: I was using that before but it simply throw an error. What i want is to put something in front of the form that is wrong to print what is missing. I'm aware of thoses print, this is for debug only, thanks tho

Comment: You can also display all form errors (you have them in form.errors), like here: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1094/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `clean_cols` that you call after `is_valid()` you should implement `clean` method and do these validations there.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other for more details.

Comment: Thanks, but would it allow me to print errors notifications that are user friendly ? I mean by that not printing out some debbug page or a new page saying that some internal error happend ?

Comment: If you implement clean method it will show errors as you expect - on your form page. There are two ways to tell django about errors: raise `ValidationError` or you could use `self._errors[FIELD_NAME]` as you already do if you want to show several errors at the same time. When you raise `ValidationError` exceptions outside of `clean` or `clean_*` methods django doesn't handle them as you excepct and you see 500 error page.

Comment: Ok ! Thanks, i'm going to fix that. For some reasons when i simply changed the clean_cols to clean method it didn't pass the ifs i made to check the data, does clean have some special things to know about ?

Comment: Not really, You just need to get cleaned_data: `super(FORM_CLASS_NAME, self).clean()` and finally return that cleaned data. It should works fine.

Comment: I've edited the topic to be able to show you how i've changed it. That's what i've done but still seems like a big NOP

Comment: use `cleaned_file_type = cleaned_data['file_type']` instead of `cleaned_file_type = self.cleaned_data.get("file_type")`. `self` is unnecessary

Comment: Still get trought with  cleaned_file_type = cleaned_data['file_type'], cleaned_file_cols = cleaned_data['file_cols']

Comment: Ok got it, it goes in the if statement but no error at all are printed (it actually stops everything once it reads the raise Validation error)